# An application of the Base Change Theorem to the moduli space of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let $S$ be an abelian or K3 surface, $H$ an ample class on $S$, $v\in H^{ev}(S,\mathbb{Z})$ and $M$ the moduli space of $H$-stable sheaves on $S$ with invariants fixed by $v$. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a universal sheaf on $M\times S$. I indicate with $\pi_{ij}$ the projection from $M\times S\times M$ to the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ factors. My goal is to show that the relative Ext sheaf
$$ \mathcal{E}xt^2_{\pi_{13}}(\pi^*_{12}\mathcal{E},\pi^*_{23}\mathcal{E})$$
is a line bundle supported on the diagonal $\Delta\subset M\times M$. I had solved this problem in the following way. First of all let's recall the (one of the corollary) Base Change Theorem as stated in Mumford, Abelian Varieties:

let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper morphism of noetherian schemes and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf on $X$. If $\dim H^p(X_y,\mathcal{F}_y)$ is constant for every $y\in Y$, then $R^pf_*\mathcal{F}$ is locally free and $R^pf_*\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}k(y)=H^p(X_y,\mathcal{F}_y)$, where $k(y)$ is the field at $y$.

Let's apply this with $f=\pi_{13}$ and $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{H}om(\pi^*_{12}\mathcal{E},\pi^*_{23}\mathcal{E})$. Since $M$ parametrizes stable sheaves on $S$, the latter sheaves is supported on the diagonal. On the other hand, since both $M$ and $S$ are symplectic, Serre duality assures us that also $\mathcal{E}xt^2_{\pi_{13}}(\pi^*_{12}\mathcal{E},\pi^*_{23}\mathcal{E})$ is supported on the diagonal. If $(m,m)=([F],[F])\in\Delta$, where $[F]$ is the class of a stable sheaf on $S$, then $$\dim H^2(X_{(m,m)},\mathcal{F}_{(m,m)})=\dim H^2(S,\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_S}(F,F))=$$$$=\dim Ext^2(F,F)=\dim End(F)^{\vee}=1$$ where we used Serre duality and the fact that a stable sheaf is simple. Hence the BCT implies that $R^2\pi_{13,*}\mathcal{H}om(\pi^*_{12}\mathcal{E},\pi^*_{23}\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{E}xt^2_{\pi_{13}}(\pi^*_{12}\mathcal{E},\pi^*_{23}\mathcal{E})$ is locally free of rank $1$.

Anyway, I have recently looked at the Mukai paper, 'On the moduli space of bundle on K3 surfaces I', Proposition 4.10, where there is Mukai's proof of this statement. It turns out that his proof is quite different: he uses a fact about the diagonal, e.g. the ideal of sheaves $\mathcal{I}_{\Delta}$ annihilates $\mathcal{E}xt^2_{\pi_{13}}(\pi^*_{12}\mathcal{E},\pi^*_{23}\mathcal{E})$. Of course I trust Mukai more than myself. Nevertheless, I cannot see why and where I need that remark in my argument.

Can anybody point out some errors in my argument and suggest how to fix them?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: as Bernie noted, I cannot use the classical Base Change Theorem in this case and I need the ext-formulation (see the referement in the comments under Bernie's answer). Up to this modification, the conclusion looks 'formally' right. Anyway, why does Mukai need that $\mathcal{I}_{\Delta}$ annihilates $\mathcal{E}xt^2_{\pi_{13}}(\pi^*_{12}\mathcal{E},\pi^*_{23}\mathcal{E})$?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment due to reputation and haven't done the computations, but I see two possible problems:

- usually one has a spectral sequence $(R^if_{*})(\mathcal{E}xt^j(M,N)) => \mathcal{E}xt_f^{i+j}(M,N)$ because $f_{*}\mathcal{H}om(M,-)$ is a composition of functors.
- $Ext^2(F,F)=H^2(\mathcal{H}om(F,F))$ only holds if $F$ is locally free, due to local to global spectral sequence for $Ext$.

What may be helpful: there is a base change theorem for relative Ext-sheaves, ma be this can help you

Comment: thank you for your comments. With your first remark, do you mean that I cannot write $R^2\pi_{13,*}\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{E}xt^2_{\pi_{13}}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{E})$? This should be because the spectral sequence doesn't converge in general at page $2$..?

Comment: For what concern the second remark, maybe I can avoid to use it. In fact, I can pass from $H^2(\mathcal{H}om(F,F))$ to $H^0(\mathcal{H}om(F,F))^{\vee}$ by duality and get the same information. What do you think about?

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant with regards to the spectral sequence, we cannot write the relative Ext in general in that form. For the second question: i don't think $\mathcal{H}om(F,F)$ is selfdual if $F$ is not locally free, that is Serre duality does not work. We only have $Ext^2(F,F)\cong Hom(F,F)^{\vee}$. I recommend to look in the article "Universal family of extensions" of H.Lange. There is a base change formula which may help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read at that paper and let you know!

Comment: Ok, I have checked. Basically, as I could image, the Base Change for ext follows from the classical one up to a locally free resolution. The remarks you have pointed out are solved if I use this 'new' formulation. Thank you, I'll edit the question to point out this.

Comment: Anyway, I still cannot see why Mukai uses a different approach. Or if the one used by him is the same one under some remarks...

Comment: I don't know if the two approaches are basically the same, maybe this is the case. But Mukai needs the fact that $\mathcal{I}_{\Delta}$ annihilates the sheaf, because then the relative Ext is the pushforward of a sheaf on the diagonal to the whole of $M\times M$. This sheaf is the line bundle Mukai talks about. Meanwhile I found another proof of this fact in Huybrechts and Lehn, it is in the chapter about low dimensional examples of moduli spaces on K3-surfaces, it explains what happens a little bit more.

Comment: Yes I forgot HuybrechtsLehn book! In fact their use of spectral sequence is just a rigorous way to use Base Change avoiding our digression on ext-Base Change. I have really appreciated your comments on the ideal $\mathcal{I}_{\Delta}$: my argument works when I only look at $\Delta$ and the restriction of my sheaf to it. Since I want to see this as a sheaf on the whole $M\times M$, I need to globalize and this is the way. Thank you very much for your suggestions, my view is pretty clearer now.